# Obtain the names of rows of a matrix in which every element is greater than a value

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

```
 x <- matrix (1:20,ncol=4)
 rownames(x) <-c(letters[1:5])
 x
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    1    6   11   16
b    2    7   12   17
c    3    8   13   18
d    4    9   14   19
e    5   10   15   20
```

Now I would like to obtain the names of rows in which every element is greater than 3, i.e. "d" and "e"

Comment: `rownames(x)[ rowSums(x>3) == ncol(x) ]`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to generate an index using `apply` and `all({some expression})` and use that to subset your rownames. In this case:

```
idx <- apply(x, 1, function(x) all(x>3))
rownames(x)[idx]
```